# CGAL Linking Error QT Creator Project for Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10, qt-creator, cgal

I have problems creating a project using QT with CGAL and Boost on Windows 10.

In this project there are a few .pro Files and all projects without CGAL have compiled. Boost also works without problems. If I compile the CGAL Project i get linking errors:

Link Errors

[image]

Here is my .pro file

```
win32:INCLUDEPATH += C:/CGAL32/include/
win32:INCLUDEPATH += C:/CGAL32/build/include/
win32:INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost_lib_inc/include/
win32:INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost/boost_1_68_0/

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -LC:/CGAL32/auxiliary/gmp/lib -lgmp-10 -lmpfr-4 -LC:/CGAL32/build/lib/Release  -lCGAL-vc140-mt-4.12.1 -lCGAL_Core-vc140-mt-4.12.1
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -LC:/CGAL32/auxiliary/gmp/lib -lgmp-10 -lmpfr-4 -LC:/CGAL32/build/lib/Debug -lCGAL-vc140-mt-gd-4.12.1 -lCGAL_Core-vc140-mt-gd-4.12.1
else:unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lCGAL
```

On Linux all works fine.

Comment: The errors is see would come from the fact that the CGAL library is not linked. But from what I see you asked to linked with CGAL. I have no idea if you would get an error if you asked to link with something that does not exist and I would check whether the CGAL lib is really linked with. An alternative is to use the header only mode of CGAL. See [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html#title14) for details.